# How to open notification when app is closed [Flutter][OneSignal]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, onesignal

I am using Flutter with OneSignal. All the configs and handlers are working as expected when app is opened or in background. But not when closed.
I receive notifications if app is closed, but when i tap on them, the app opens but with no params attached and not triggering the event handlers associated to the notification receive.

I have been wondering if my onesignal init script is misplaced.
And i wanted to know if anyone else have been suffering the same issue. Because i cannot find any issue related.

```
class FonixTelematicsApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FonixTelematicsAppState createState() => _FonixTelematicsAppState();
}

class _FonixTelematicsAppState extends State<FonixTelematicsApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
   if (!mounted) return;

await pushService.init();
  eventBus.on<AppPushOpenEvent>().listen(
    (AppPushOpenEvent event) => onAppPushNotification(event.notification));
  }

  onAppPushNotification(OSNotification notification) {
    var data = notification.payload.additionalData;
    Map<String, dynamic> pages = {
      'alarm': (Map<dynamic, dynamic> alert) {
        Map<String, dynamic> alertData = {'id': alert['id']};
        return {
          'route': Routes.alertDetails,
          'arguments': new AlertDetailsPageArguments(
              alert: Alert.fromJson(alertData), isPushNotification: true)
        };
      },
      'auth': (Map<dynamic, dynamic> properties) {
        return {
          'route': Routes.auth,
          'arguments': new AuthPageArguments(key: properties['key'])
        };
      }
    };

    if (pages[data['page']] != null) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> pageData = data['data'];
      Map<String, dynamic> page = pages[data['page']](pageData);

      debugPrint('Will push new page! ${page.toString()}');
      navigatorKey.currentState
          .pushNamed(page['route'], arguments: page['arguments']);
    } else {
      debugPrint(
          'onAppPushNotification: unrecognized payload ${notification.payload}');
    }
  }
}
```

push-service.dart

```
class PushService extends BasePushService {
  Future<void> init() async {
    // OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);

    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
      var data = notification.payload.additionalData;
      if (data['page'] == 'auth') {
        eventBus.fire(AppPushOpenEvent(notification));
      }
    });
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((data) {
      eventBus.fire(AppPushOpenEvent(data.notification));
    });
    OneSignal.shared
        .setInAppMessageClickedHandler((OSInAppMessageAction action) {
          print(action);
        });
    OneSignal.shared
        .setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {
      print("SUBSCRIPTION STATE CHANGED: ${changes.jsonRepresentation()}");
      _subscriptionObserver(changes);
    });
    OneSignal.shared.setPermissionObserver((OSPermissionStateChanges changes) {
      debugPrint("PERMISSION STATE CHANGED: ${changes.jsonRepresentation()}");
    });

    await OneSignal.shared
        .init("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx", iOSSettings: {
      OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: true,
      OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true,
      OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: false
    });

    OneSignal.shared
        .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
  }
}
```

Comment: After some deep research i found a very deep possibility with Deep Links :D
Still have not try it! But i will update this issue after some implementation.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/links

Comment: After some trial and error and reading carefully the documentation, deep linking works correctly, but not according to the real expectations. What I mean is that when clicking the push it will only trigger the Launch URL section when app is loaded. Making it almost useless to solve the problem of execute the actions if app is closed.

Comment: I'm not sure about [this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-notifications-work#notifications-when-app-is-closed) behavior: "*A normal close such as swiping your app away is a normal close and won't be an issue on most devices. However, force-closing it through the app settings, task killer, or through Android Studio would result in most Intents (including pushes) preventing services from starting.*" Could this be the reason?